# Google protobuf cannot be compiled because of poor code(generates warnings)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, shared-libraries, protocol-buffers

Google protobuf library(included in my project) cannot be compiled, because it contains poor code that generates warnings.

I treat all warnings as errors and I don't want to disable these warnings in the project because of this one library.

Where do I find working(high quality without warnings) version of Google protobuf?

Comment: you fork the repo, fix the warnings and push the patch

Comment: you didn't pay a dime for this software. It's an open-source fork which google kindly made available to you for free. As an open source user you have a moral obligation to either say "thank you", or fix the problem.

Comment: @RichardHodges I would suggest there's a third option of "acknowledge that it doesn't meet your specific needs and walk away"

Comment: @RichardHodges: Noone blames them, it's only curiosity about the problem